# Array after change returns blank in Radgrid

Tags: javascript, arrays, radgrid

When i change my row and bind it again with my radgrid it gives my blank row .
I want to edit my array on the base of index . Why it gives me a blank row ? I can't figure out what i am doing wrong here ?

```
   function btn1Click() {

       var newRow = [];
       var cot = 0;
    var sn = document.getElementById('sno').value;
    var type = document.getElementById('type').value;
    var act = document.getElementById("htitle").options[document.getElementById('htitle').selectedIndex].text;
    var ct = document.getElementById("job").options[document.getElementById('job').selectedIndex].text;
    var db = document.getElementById('drr').value;
    var cr = document.getElementById('crr').value;
    var desc = document.getElementById('disc').value;

    var data = [{ "SNO": 1, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 2, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 3, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 4, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 5, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 6, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 7, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 8, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 9, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 10, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 11, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 12, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 13, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 14, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr },
    { "SNO": 15, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr }

    ];


        data[0] = [{ "SNO": 11, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr }]
        console.log(data[0]);
        console.log(data);
        var mtv = $find("radGridView2").get_masterTableView();
        mtv.set_dataSource(data); mtv.dataBind();

    }

</script>
```

this is what my grid looks like when i change the row .
[image: RADGRID]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by changing this

```
 data[0] = [{ "SNO": 11, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr }]
```

To

```
 data[0] = { "SNO": 11, "INITIAL": type, "TITLE": act, "DISC": desc, "JOB": ct, "dRR": db, "cRR": cr }
```

only **[ ]**  was the problem